# how to store json objects in mariadb?

Tags: json, mariadb

```
{
"client_request": {
"id": 29318,
"pincode": 110009,
"client_order_id": "66967604933444",
"pickup_address": {
"pincode": 411026,
"id": 26269,
"address": "Khasra No. 93/5 94/1 Phirni Road Vill- Mundka New
Delhi Delhi"
},
"skus": [{
"client_sku_id": "SC45634",
"price": null,
"id": 26267,
"product_name": "xyz"
}]
```

}

here i don't know what might be the number of json objects in skus ..
i read about dynamic col in maria db but then using dynamic col i am having problem storing array of json object ..

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like 2 tables, no JSON:

- client_requests
- skus (with the id of the client_request for which it applies)

I don't know what the current `id` is -- perhaps it came from a database implementation?